# Wordpress displays widgets out of whack

Tags: pages, design

I am using a piece of Javascript that creates a countdown timer that looks good everywhere else but on Wordpress sites.

For example, [this has been done with Ontraport page builder](http://hesams.respond.ontraport.net/) and it looks great.

But the similar code in a [WordPress site](https://webmoosh.com/with-timer/) looks pretty out of whack.

What would be the best way to get rid of all the extra blocks of code and CSS WordPress adds?

Thanks

Here is the embedded code:

```
<div id = "countdown_timer" style="position:fixed; width: 100%; bottom:0; z-index:1000;" ><script type="text/javascript" src="https://timerz.xyz/timer/egc.php" data-launch_owner_email_hashed="94bd214b329301668349352de430bb6d" data-launch_id="204" ></script></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress isn't adding anything that's messing with it. The problem is that on Ontraport you placed it at the very top in a full-width div. On your WordPress site you placed it in the content area, which is not full width. So the left edge of where it appears is not on the edge of the screen. You've made it `position: fixed`, and aligned it to the top with `top: 0` (or the bottom, it's different on the site compared to the code you've pasted here), but you haven't aligned it to the left with `left: 0;`. Add it and it will appear in the proper place:

```
<div id = "countdown_timer" style="position:fixed; width: 100%; left: 0; bottom:0; z-index:1000;" ><script type="text/javascript" src="https://timerz.xyz/timer/egc.php" data-launch_owner_email_hashed="94bd214b329301668349352de430bb6d" data-launch_id="204" ></script></div>
```

Comment: Adding left:0 fixed it. Also I added it as the first thing in page editor: ibb.co/kfuCrK . In WP how can I add the code "on top of content area"? Thanks

Comment: Generally you can’t. You’d need to edit the theme file directly.